# How can I send pdf file to spool in SAP?

Tags: pdf, abap, spool

I have a program that programmatically creates XFT template for PDF and XFD template for data. I can download PDF file and it all works just fine, except spool request. How can create a spool request, then pass my custom PDF file to that request?

Comment: you wanna automate sending PDFs to email? is it a custom transaction or standard extension? what is the use-case?

Answer (score 1):

You can check **FP_TEST_SAVE_PDF_TO_SPOOL** program which is used for ADS pdf files.